# From commands to recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode

I am currently on Ubuntu 18.04.02. The problem is that I can not log in. When I put my password everything goes in black screen. I tried everything. My idea is to run it in recovery mode, but I can not. I am trying to get in grub menu but instead of this I am getting into grub command line prompt. Is there any command to run recovery mode from grub console?

Comment: Do you have another account you could try logging in with? (Which, BTW, is one of those things everyone should do: create a special Admin/root account to be used just for emergencies like this).

Comment: I tried, but it is not working too

Comment: go to a different tty `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F<2-9>` and see if you can log in from there

Comment: Unluckily this shortcuts do nothing

Comment: What do you mean they do nothing? Do it before you put your password in

Comment: I did it before and after, my computer does not respond on it

Answer (score 0):

I find solution. The problem was with nvidia drivers. I had wrong drivers installed. I do not why, but finally grub menu showed. So I chose recovery mode and installed good drivers.